# NSUserDefaults not working when opening a nib programmatically

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nswindowcontroller

In the window which shows up at launch and NSUserDefaults works great with the initial window. If i open the same nib file again programmatically with this code:

```
NSWindowController *controller = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainMenu"];
[controller showWindow:self];
```

it fails to get the NSUserDefaults. I get the value of `(null)`.  I read the defaults like this:
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myKey"];`

and write to them like this:
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"myValue" forKey:@"myKey"];`

What am I doing wrong? Once the value is set and I relaunch the application, reopen the prog. loaded nib window it fails!

I open this programmatically opened window from the class which the NIB file is hooked up to -> The user presses a button and the 2nd window opens!

Comment: Is your [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] returning null or your valueForKey call?

Comment: The valueForKey call is returning null, I think, when I NSLog() [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults], I get the address, which is the same in both windows!

Comment: If it works with an IB instantiated window, but not one created programmatically, there's probably some connection you're making in IB that you're not properly reconnecting to the controller.  I doubt the problem is with NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Post the actual code where you're getting the value from defaults and testing it.

Comment: @Flyingdiver it is an IBAction I have. The Other code works perfectly, only the NSUserDefaults not.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're using "setObject:@"string" and "StringforKey" and you just replaced it w/ "value" in your example?

Comment: I repeat - post the actual code from the IBAction method.  There's something missing from your explanation.  You already said that you're getting a valid pointer to the standardUserDefaults.  So either your key is bad or you're doing something wrong with the value that you get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself now. I had a NSUserDefaults variable defined in the .h so i can access it on the whole .m file. I was initializing it, `mainDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, in the `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{}`, which was only called when the application started! When I opened a new window, that wasn't called of course!

Anyway, thanks for your help.